# Question regarding the function $z=a+bi \mapsto f(z)=a+i(a+b)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I'm preparing for an exam, and I have come over the following problem:
I have the function $f$, where C is a set of complex numbers
$$f: C \to C,$$ 
$$z=a+bi \mapsto f(z)=a+i(a+b)$$ 
Is the function of the form $f(z) = z + w$, where $w$ does not depend on $z$? Is it of the form $z\cdot w$ (where $w$ does not depend on $z$)?

For the first part, my answer is 'no', seeing as $w=ai$ for the identity to hold, and it is then clear that $w$ depends on $z$. My teacher's solution says the same thing, but that the answer to the question is 'yes'. Am i wrong, or is my teacher wrong?

For the second part of the exercise: I have written $w=c+di$, which gives $z·w=(ac-bd)+ (bc+ad)i$. This gives us two equations, namely: $$ac-bd=a$$ and $$bc+ad=a+b$$

I tried solving this system of linear equations for $c$ and $d$, and ended up with $c=d=1$. However this only holds if $b=0$. I am a bit stuck, and can't really see clearly how to proceed, or how to come to a general conclusion.

Please let me know if something was unclear, or if I should explain more clearly what I have done. Thank you in advance!

EDIT (included my teacher's answer, which I do not understand):

In his solution, my teacher ends up with the same system of linear equations as I did in my post. From there he says that the system has a unique solution if and only if the determinant of the matrix $$ \begin{matrix}a&-b\\a&b\end{matrix}$$ is non-zero. That is $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$.Then he says:
But if $a^2+b^2=0 \Rightarrow a=b=0 \Rightarrow f(z) = 0 = 0 · w$ Hence the answer to the question must be 'yes'. If anyone could help me understand what is meant, I would greatly appreciate it. NB: There is a possibility that my teacher has read the task wrong, and therefore answers 'yes' when the answer to both questions is 'no'.

Comment: It seems to me that the best person to ask about this would be your teacher...

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the first question: you are right. The question is equivalent to this one: is the function $z\mapsto f(z)-z$ constant? No, it is not: $f(z)-z=i\operatorname{Re}z$.

Concerning the other question, just note that $f(1)=1+i=(1+i)\times1$. So, if there was such a $w$, $w=1+i$. But $f(i)=i\neq(1+i)\times i$. Therefore, there is no such $w$ (again).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This very much makes sense to me, and fits very well with my initial thoughts. What confuses me is my teacher's answers to this task. I will edit my post to include his answer, which I do not understand.

Comment: To be clear: What you meant is that the only possible $w=1+i$ (as seen from solving my system of linear equations). However, from what you showed, this can't either be a solution, and hence the answer must be 'no'?

Comment: @Mathstudent Yes, that's it.

Comment: @Mathstudent If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: Yes, it was very helpful! However, could you also check out my edit, and see if you can help me with that also? I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Since $$ w = {f(z)\over z}={a+i(a+b)\over a+bi}=1 +{ai\over a+bi}$$ this is not independent of $z$.